# Is this CW complex a torus?

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

In Hatcher's book, the torus as a CW complex is constructed so:

[image]

But as far as I see, I can follow the gluing instruction also in the following way.

I draw the vertex $p$ and the edges $a$ and $b$ so:

[image]

Then I draw this picture on a big sphere, and the big region of the sphere that is out of these small disks will be the 2-cell. As far as I see it is glued as is required for beeing a torus (these small disks will be the two holes of the torus). Is this construction really good? Is it really a torus, or I missed something?

Comment: What is end up with is really something homotopic to $\mathbb S^2$ minus two points and this is not a torus.

Comment: What do you mean by two holes of a torus?

Comment: What do you identify after removing the small open disks

Comment: No, the gluing is not correct

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Could you show me where is the failure?

Comment: @StefanHamcke I don' identify anythig. Both ends of $a$ and both ends of $b$ is $p$, just as in the official torus. And the boundary of the 2-cell is $a+b$ in both cases. Still don't see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

The construction that you did does not lead to a torus. As mentioned by John in the comments what you get is homotopic to $S^2$ minus two points which is homeomorphic to a cylinder. You can then quotient out the cylinder to get a torus.

Comment: Are you sure? The cylinder is a 2-manifold, but as far as I see, in my object the point $p$ doestn't have an environment that is homeomorphic to an open 2-disk.

Comment: @mma Your space is homotopic to the cylinder as the cylinder is homeomorphic to $\mathbb S^2$ minus two points.

Comment: Oh, yes, I was superficial. I thought of homeomorphism, but you told homotopic equivalence. Yes, my object is really homotopic equivalent to the cylinder. Still I don't see where is the difference between the two kind of glues.